# Magento ver. 1.9.3.2 not logging anything at all

Tags: php, log, error-log, magento-1.9.3.2

I have noticed magento all of a sudden has stopped logging things, nothing gets logged anymore. Why could this be happening ? I would like to debug log paypal standard orders but nothing gets logged.

I checked my settings and can confirm that logging is turned on:

[image: Log settings]

However checking the files, there is nothing in them and they are all owned by apache and for now have been given 777 permissions.

My .htaccess includes:

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE=true
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mag19/var/vishphp.log
```

My index.php includes:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: Ok. Try this. Open your view.phtml and in the very first line add this code `Mage::log('checking log',null,'check.log',true);` And open any product page and check if it creates the logfile or not. If not i would suggest checking the var folder permission. And that "TRUE" parameter logs something forcefully.

Comment: @KingshukDeb your suggestion didn't work. No file created in /var/log

Comment: I have the same issue. PHP errors are logged in the PHP error log. For fatal Magento errors, reports are created. But exception.log and system.log stay empty.

Comment: Could be that magento running into permission issue to write to them, do a chown to the web user. e.g. apache